# Using mediaprojectionmanager to get screenshots while another app is in the foreground

Tags: android, service, mediaprojectionmanager

Working on a personal project to use the media projection manager API to create an Android app that allows me to take a screenshot whenever I say, 'screenshot' and then convert it to bitmap and sends it off to another function for processing.  Which then recognizes what's in the image and speaks it aloud. However, the documentation is not good, and the examples have looked at on forums have led me to this code which still doesn't work. Firstly it throws several errors in Android studio. But even if I try to solve those at best I just get a black bitmap or the app crashes. I've got a foreground service running in the background that calls the screen capture service. Here's what the screencaptureservice looks like currently.  Been working on it for a week and it's a real headache.

class ScreenshotService : Service() {

```
private lateinit var mediaProjectionManager: MediaProjectionManager

private lateinit var mediaProjection: MediaProjection

private lateinit var imageReader: ImageReader

private lateinit var handler: Handler

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {

    return null

}

override fun onCreate() {

    super.onCreate()

    // Initialize MediaProjectionManager and create a Handler on the main looper

    mediaProjectionManager = getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager

    handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    // Start the media projection when the service is started

    startMediaProjection()

    return START_STICKY

}

private fun startMediaProjection() {

    // Retrieve the resultCode and data Intent extras passed to the service

    val resultCode = intent?.getIntExtra("resultCode", -1)

    val data = intent?.getParcelableExtra<Intent>("data")

    if (resultCode != -1 && data != null) {

        // Get a MediaProjection instance using the MediaProjectionManager

        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data)

        val windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

        val metrics = DisplayMetrics()

        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)

        // Set up an ImageReader to capture screenshots

        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2)

        mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(

            "Screenshot",

            metrics.widthPixels,

            metrics.heightPixels,

            metrics.densityDpi,

            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,

            imageReader.surface,

            null,

            null

        )

        // Start capturing screenshots in the background

        captureScreenshots()

    }

}

private fun captureScreenshots() {

    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->

        val image = reader.acquireLatestImage()

        if (image != null) {

            // Process the screenshot here

            val bitmap = imageToBitmap(image)

            saveBitmapToFile(bitmap)

            image.close()

        }

    }, handler)

}

private fun imageToBitmap(image: Image): Bitmap {

    val planes = image.planes

    val buffer: ByteBuffer = planes[0].buffer

    val pixelStride: Int = planes[0].pixelStride

    val rowStride: Int = planes[0].rowStride

    val rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * image.width

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(

        image.width + rowPadding / pixelStride,

        image.height,

        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888

    )

    // Copy the image data to the bitmap

    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)

    return bitmap

}

private fun saveBitmapToFile(bitmap: Bitmap) {

    // Save the bitmap to a file or perform any desired action

    try {

        val fos = FileOutputStream("/path/to/screenshot.png")

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)

        fos.close()

    } catch (e: IOException) {

        e.printStackTrace()

    }

}
```

}

Any help appreciated,   I know it's easier to just use a screen reader, etc, but that's not what I'm trying to do. Love challenges but still pretty new to android

Comment: "or the app crashes" -- [use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html). FWIW, I have a chapter on media projection in [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android/), including multiple sample apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare interestingly I ran across your book earlier while looking for help in an older post. Downloaded it and it's very informative,  but the code I came up with from working through the screenshot chapter section still resulted in blank bitmaps. Since you're obviously an expert, could I pick your brain a bit and ask for help?

Comment: That's interesting. I haven't used the media projection APIs much since writing that chapter. And, looking at the dates on the screenshots, that was 8 years ago.  (though the `andshooter` one is a bit newer) Are you saying that the samples as written no longer work? Or that they work, but you are having difficulty adapting them to your situation?

Comment: Initially the code just returned a black bitmap.  However that seems to be an issue with android 13 as several other posts on here detail reasons for that. Just revisited the chapter, still trying to adapt it to run error free and keep the MediaProjectionManager active so that i dont need to grant permission each time when called from code instead of a notification

Comment: A foreground service is pretty much your only option, and even that will have limitations courtesy of manufacturer meddling.

Comment: The image format in your code throws an error, i tried jpg and several others,  they all give 'incomparable format' errors at runtime. It's this line.        imageReader=ImageReader.newInstance(width, height,
        PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);      any ideas?

Comment: No, sorry. But, you might look at [this project](https://github.com/cvzi/ScreenshotTile), which seems to be actively maintained and uses the `MediaProjection` API.

Comment: That looks very helpful as its directly relevant to my project.  Thank you!